# Enviar form HTML sem o botão submit

Tags: javascript, html

É possível criar um *form* HTML que envie automaticamente os dados do *form*?
Ex: tenho um *form* somente com `radiobutton` e por motivo de estética não quero colocar o botão enviar, seria possível criar isso?

Comment: Sim, por javascript podes fazer isso.

Comment: Entendi, é que esse form será enviado em e-mails marketing e o javascript é altamente vulnerável a transformar o e-mail em spam... não tem jeito, vou ter que colocar o botão submit.

Obrigado!

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 11):

É possível com JavaScript. De forma bem simples:

```
<form name="formulario" action="form.php">
    Digite algo: <input type="text" name="campo">
    <a href="javascript: submitform()">Envie</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform() {
        document.formulario.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Também é possível usar técnicas mais avançadas como [AJAX](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) e/ou utilizar bibliotecas que ajudam nisso, como a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Mas o  comentário adicional indica que está usando a ferramenta bem errada para o que deseja.

Veja uma das formas por jQuery usando [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/AJAX/BasicExample.js).

Comment: Mas daí não consigo usar em email Marketing, é arriscado ir direto para a caixa de spam

Comment: Você sequer deve usar isto para fazer *e-mail marketing*. Mas mesmo que use, deve ter um bom motivo para isto ser considerado *spam*, então parece que é melhor você não fazer coisas que são consideradas erradas. Qualquer coisa errada que você faça poderá ser considerado *spam* por algum *anti-spam*, até mesmo algumas coisas coisas certas. O que eu percebo é que você quer enviar dados sem anuência de alguém e não é a presença do botão de `submit` que faz algo ser classificado como *spam*, é fazer coisa erada. Tem como resolver o seu problema mas não vou ensinar porque é errado, é enganoso.

Comment: Entendi, mas não são dados comprometedores, já resolvi o problema por aqui. Obrigado!

Comment: Qualquer dado de alguém, mesmo seja um "x" qualquer enviado sem ele saber que está sendo enviado é algo errado e em última análise pode até mesmo ser considerado ilegal e gerar um processo.

Answer (score 8):

Enviar um formulário automáticamente precisa de javascript.
Porem há maneiras de contornar mais ou menos eficientes.

Se a questão é estética vale a pena lembrar que um `button` pode ser facilmente alterado para ter outro aspeto. Ainda mais fácil é alterar um `label` de um `button` ou `input` que permite fazer o submit sem na verdade ter de ter o `button`/`input` visivel.

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/b9wnw9c6/**

Código do exemplo:

HTML

```
<form action="teste.php">
    <label for="enviar">Carregue aqui para enviar</label>
    <input type="submit" id="enviar" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
label {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #cff;
}
input[type=submit] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Boa idéia. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

acho que é isso que tava querendo, tambem to querendo algo do tipo

Você precisa ouvir o evento lançada por seu formulário e processar seu formulário antes de o enviar .

Você pode seguir este exemplo para executar esta tarefa :

```
$(function() {
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent sending the form before we processed the form

    var active_input        =   $(".active")[0];        
    var active_input_value  =   active_input.val();

    $.ajax({
            url     :   "php_file_to_call.php"
        ,   method  :   "post"
        ,   data    :   { something : active_input_value }
    });
});
```

});

A chamada Ajax (que poderia ter sido um $ .post ()) é necessário, pois você não pode enviar o formulário real, porque ela não impede elemento un -ativo a ser enviada.

[iEnviar form em apenas 1 input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882611/send-only-one-input-value-with-form-submit-in-php)

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/54924)

Comment: Ta certo coloquei o que encontrei aqui, tenho apenas conhecimento basico sobre isso, porem o raciocinio do rapaz me parece logico

Comment: A resposta está parcialmente em ingles. TRaduza-a para se adequar ao site.

Answer (score 1):

Com javascript:

```js
var form = new FormData();
form.append('post1', document.getElementById('radiobutton1').value);
form.append('post2', document.getElementById('radiobutton2').value);
form.append('postN', document.getElementById('radiobuttonN').value);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('post', 'arquivo.php');
request.send(form);
```